# ray.exceptions.RayActorError: The actor died unexpectedly before finishing this task

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ray

i was running a [project from github](https://github.com/dnandha/mopac.git) which use ray. Then i met this error and have no idea how to fix it
output:
`(pid=3451) 2024-03-18 04:05:30.102745: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:124] Allocation of 5600000000 exceeds 10% of system memory.                            2024-03-18 04:05:40,734 ERROR worker.py:1752 -- A worker died or was killed while executing task 00000000e8e30890e0a1c55cabe41e1c5567a2b4.                           2024-03-18 04:05:40,786 ERROR trial_runner.py:426 -- Error processing event.  Traceback (most recent call last):                                                 File "/usr/local/envs/mopac/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 389, in _process_events                                                  result = self.trial_executor.fetch_result(trial) File "/usr/local/envs/mopac/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/ray_trial_executor.py", line 252, in fetch_result result = ray.get(trial_future[0]) File "/usr/local/envs/mopac/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 2288, in get raise value ray.exceptions.RayActorError: The actor died unexpectedly before finishing this task.`

[mycode](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1orQqZXY-BBPnOnVB4ZouRSlX33lMb8bP?usp=sharing)

[trial_runner](https://pastebin.pl/view/f98c0b8a)

[ray_trial_executor](https://pastebin.pl/view/5313cfcc)

[worker](https://pastebin.pl/view/4fe94cfb)

i have tried to find some solution in internet but it seem not similar to my error or i just can't clearly understand how to fix it.
i think there is no problem about memory because it was 9.4/12.7gb ram when this error occured